# mod_rewrite issue with query_string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite url request which have specific key words to https.
I am getting issue with the `QUERY_STRING`.

```
RewriteRule "^.*dev" "/so/me/path/redirect.jsp?dest=/so/me/path/orig.21.10.shtml?my_name=launch&my_class=english_20&my_take=net-thing_1100" [QSA,PT]
```

issue is whenever mod_rewrite interupt i am getting the rewrite rule up to  `"/so/me/path/redirect.jsp?dest=/so/me/path/orig.21.10.shtml?my_name=launch"` much only. It skips the `Query_String` even after mentioning the QSA parameter.

Arumon

Comment: That’s likely because you have _two_ `?` in there. If you want the second one to be part of the `dest` parameter value, then you have to URL-encode it properly (`%3f`). (You _might_ have to use the `B` flag as well, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)

Comment: I can see both of my ? marks are properly rewriting, but the problem is with & . I tried your suggession, but not luck.